# Jersey Custom Exception Not Caught in Servlet Class?

Tags: java, exception, servlets, jersey

I am using Below Custom Exception class in my project

```
public class BadRequestException extends WebApplicationException {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private String message;
    public BadRequestException(String message) {
        super();
        this.message = message;
    }
    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }
    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }
}
```

I have created a Mapper class also..

```
public class BadRequestExceptionMapper implements ExceptionMapper<BadRequestException> {
    public Response toResponse(BadRequestException brexec) {
        return Response.status(Response.Status.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).entity(brexec.getResponse().getEntity()).type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).build();
    }
}
```

I am calling my service through a **Servlet** and the Exception is thrown by one of its method but i am not able to catch it in Servlet class.I have used below code to catch the exception..

```
    try{
    //Some Business logic then
    service.path("restful").path("jwbservice/" + methodName + "/" + id).header("lid", lid).delete(String.class);
    }
    catch (BadRequestException ex) {
    out.println(ex);
    } 
   catch(Exception exe){
    out.println(exe);
    }
```

And the service method i have used this code in my Service class which will throw the exception.

```
@DELETE
    @Path("/deleteLink/{id}")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public String deleteLink(@PathParam("id") int id, @HeaderParam("lid") String lid) throws BadRequestException {
    if (id<= 0) {
        throw new BadRequestException("Required Parameter: id");
        }
//Some Business Logic
}
```

My Service **throw** the **BadRequestException** but in Servlet it is going to **Exception** catch not in **BadRequestException** Catch block.
Can any one know what i am doing wrong.

Comment: Please follow [this](http://avianey.blogspot.in/2011/12/exception-mapping-jersey.html) and try

Answer (score 0):

You will never get that exception in your servlet. This is because the servlet is effectively a REST client, and you are invoking a remote resource method to get some data. The resource call will either be successful (and some data will be mapped back), or it will fail and you will get no data (or a client side error).

On a side note, there is a problem in your server side exception mapper. You do not verify that the exception actually has a response entity before calling:

```
brexec.getResponse().getEntity()
```

In cases where the exception doesn't have a response the above code will cause a null pointer exception.

---

Some quick notes:

- Exception classes already have a `message` property. You do not need to define an additional one
- Your exception mapper needs to check for a non-existent `response` property, before trying to do something with it
- The resource path in your servlet does not appear to match the server side path. I assume that is a copy/paste error.